# Regex Color tabs in Visual Studio Community 2019 don't seem to be working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, productivity-power-tools

Previously in Visual Studio Community 2017 I had configured a series of Regex expressions to color the tabs when working in MVC according to whether these were controllers, views, models, dbcontext, and other custom conditions to find them better visually.

Now I'm testing Visual Studio 2019 and although I installed the productivity power tools, they say that the Custom Document Well component is only available for VS2017.

Here is the [page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017) to the productivity power tools

Is there another way to do the same in VS2019?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/color-coded-tabs-in-visual-studio.html) extension to color tabs in VS 2019:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for integrated functionality or open source extensions. Thanks anyway!